# How to remove a role when getting another(discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

All that I got was just this one (there, when writing (! +), He fulfills the role, but even then she is a non-worker, please help)

```
bot.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === prefix + '+') {
    member.roles.remove(801095844044341279).catch(console.error);

    }
});
```

knocks out this error

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot\index.js:40
    member.roles.remove(801095844044341279).catch(console.error);
    ^

ReferenceError: member is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot\index.js:40:5)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\user\Desktop\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Message](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object to get the member from it.

Like this:

```js
bot.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === prefix + '+') {
        msg.member.roles.remove('801095844044341279').catch(() => {
            console.error("failed to remove role");
        });
    }
});
```

I also fixed your `console.error` as it was invalid syntax, if it fails to remove the role it will error to the console properly now.